# Trying to show comments and files Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In a laravel project, in a controller im trying to show the comments and the files from database

my fuction goes like this

```
public function show($id)
    {
// with('comments')->
        $shipment = Shipment::with('comments')->where('id','=', $id)->first();
        // $shipment = Shipment::with('files')->where('id','=',$id)->first();

        return response()->json($shipment);



    }
```

I commented the file row because it was bringing me or the files or the comments, not both, and I need to retrieve the two arrays in the shipment object.

How can I add the files and the comments to shipment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing it like this:

```
$shipment = Shipment::with('comments','files')->where('id','=', $id)->first();
```

Comment: Really? now i feel dumb haha. that works perfect. thanks

Comment: Happy to help! If you find the answer is correct, kindly accept it!

Comment: i was waiting for the system to allow me to do that haha

Comment: What are the difference in the use of []          
$shipment = Shipment::with('comments','files')->where('id','=', $id)->first();      with(['comments', 'files'])->wh

Comment: It is the short way of defining an array. It's optional in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function show($id)
{

    $shipment = Shipment::with(['comments', 'files'])->where('id','=', $id)->first();

    return response()->json($shipment); 

   }
```